# Change Datatypes of One Data Frame as of Second Data Frame

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, type-conversion

I have two data frames, one have proper data types but less observations while the second has all character columns with large set of observations. I want to convert the data types of second data frame as of first matching column names. I wrote a function that works well when observations are in hundreds but ran out of memory when observations are in thousands. Please see below the script and two sample data sets. Please advise if performance can be improved.

```
convert.types <- function(df,types){
  for (i in colnames(df)){

    FUN <- switch(types[i],character = as.character, 
                  numeric = as.numeric,
                  integer = as.integer, 
                  logical = as.logical,
                  factor = as.factor)
    if(!is.null(FUN))
      df[,i] <- FUN(df[,i])
  }
  df
}

names <- c("John", "Chris", "David", "April")
ages <- c(30,35,40,45)
salaries <- c(100000,120000,140000,160000)
genders <- c("M","M","M","F")

dataframe.with.types <- data.frame ( Name=names, Age=ages, Salary=salaries, Gender=genders, Region=c("North America"), City=c("Boston", "Newyork"))
dataframe.characters <- data.frame(Name=names, Age=as.character(ages), Salary=as.character(salaries), Gender=as.character(genders), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dataframe.converted <- convert.types(dataframe.characters,sapply(dataframe.with.types,class))
```

The first data set dataframe.with.types assumes to have a few observations but with proper data types as it does. The second data set dataframe.characters is expected to have less or equal number of columns with same name but observations could be in thousands. In this case, the second data set doesn't have Region and City columns. The resultant data set dataframe.converted should be exactly same as of second but with proper datatypes as of first.

Your suggestions and feedback are highly appreciated.

Regards,

Shany

Comment: Can't you just use `dataframe.characters[] <- lapply(dataframe.characters, type.convert)`?

Comment: It doesn't change the datatypes of dataframe.characters

Comment: that means some entries in the column are not compatible with the desired class. You need to change that first